# Using random.choice with if/elif/else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, random

I'm attempting to use a random choice statement in python, with an if/elif/else statement which would continue the program. The random.choice bit works fine in the program, as it selects a random encounter, however it then chooses quite random options on the if/elif/else option. If the random.choice selects 'a giant monster' I want it to say '..you are eaten alive' and vice versa. At the moment, only the squawk and you slowly approach options seem to work, but don't necessarily correlate with the choice of monster. This is my code:

```
print("THUMP THUMP THUMP")
print("..you turn around and you see..")
monster = ("a giant monster", "a giant eagle", "a dog")
print(random.choice(monster))
monster1 = (random.choice(monster))
time.sleep(1)
if monster1 == "a giant monster":
    print(".. you are eaten alive :(")
elif monster1 == "a giant eagle":
    print("*SQUAWK*")
else:
    print("you slowly approach")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pick **two** random monsters each time. One you print, the other you assign to `monster1`:

```
print(random.choice(monster))
monster1 = (random.choice(monster))
```

Those two choices are going to be different most of the time.

Pick a monster *once*, and print that choice:

```
monster1 = random.choice(monster)
print(monster1)
```

The `if..elif..else` branching is working fine otherwise.

Comment: Knew it'd be obvious. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running:

```
print(random.choice(monster))
monster1 = (random.choice(monster))
```

hence print one random choice, and set another one into the variable

You should first set the choice into a variable, and then print it, use:

```
monster1 = (random.choice(monster))
print(monster1)
```